# Infinispan Hotrod port issue

Tags: infinispan

I am using infinispan server with HotRod for clustering. I deployed the application on serverA (11229) it works. Now I deployed it on serverB(11229) it fails.

Error:

```
"message" : "ISPN000136: Error executing command PutKeyValueCommand, writing keys [-23586]",
  "thread" : "jgroups-14,ISPN,-23586",
  "level" : "ERROR",
  "stack_trace" : "org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from -30362, see cause for remote stack traceorg.infinispan.remoting.transport.ResponseCollectors.wrapRemoteException(ResponseCollectors.java:27) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.SyncMapResponseCollector.addException(SyncMapResponseCollector.java:48) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.SyncMapResponseCollector.addException(SyncMapResponseCollector.java:26) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ValidResponseCollector.addResponse(ValidResponseCollector.java:29) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.MultiTargetRequest.onResponse(MultiTargetRequest.java:91) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.RequestRepository.addResponse(RequestRepository.java:53) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1328) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processMessage(JGroupsTransport.java:1238) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.access$200(JGroupsTransport.java:121) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport$ChannelCallbacks.receive(JGroupsTransport.java:1366) org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:819) org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:893) org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER.up(STATE_TRANSFER.java:128) org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:177) org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:343) org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:864) org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:240) org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.deliverMessage(UNICAST3.java:1002) org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.handleDataReceived(UNICAST3.java:728) org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:383) org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:600) org.jgroups.protocols.BARRIER.up(BARRIER.java:170) org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:119) org.jgroups.protocols.FD.up(FD.java:212) org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:252) org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE3.up(MERGE3.java:276) org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:262) org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1229) org.jgroups.util.SubmitToThreadPool$SingleMessageHandler.run(SubmitToThreadPool.java:87) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n\tSuppressed: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from D00DC1SJBF96R-1522, see cause for remote stack trace... 32 common frames omitted
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null  org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readWithExternalizer(GlobalMarshaller.java:694)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNonNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:679)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:361)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.BytesObjectInput.readObject(BytesObjectInput.java:40)  org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.readFrom(PutKeyValueCommand.java:121)  org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readCommandParameters(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:103)  org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readObject(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:92)  org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readObject(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:54)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readWithExternalizer(GlobalMarshaller.java:694)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNonNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:677)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:361)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.BytesObjectInput.readObject(BytesObjectInput.java:40)  org.infinispan.commands.remote.SingleRpcCommand.readFrom(SingleRpcCommand.java:47)  org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readCommandParameters(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:103)  org.infinispan.marshall.exts.CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.readObject(CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.java:116)  org.infinispan.marshall.exts.CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.readObject(CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.java:57)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readWithExternalizer(GlobalMarshaller.java:694)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNonNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:677)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:361)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromObjectInput(GlobalMarshaller.java:199)  org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(GlobalMarshaller.java:228)  org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processRequest(JGroupsTransport.java:1288)  org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processMessage(JGroupsTransport.java:1235)  org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.access$200(JGroupsTransport.java:121)  org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport$ChannelCallbacks.receive(JGroupsTransport.java:1366)  org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:819)  org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:893)  org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER.up(STATE_TRANSFER.java:128)  org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:177)  org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:359)  org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:867)  org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:240)  org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:369)  org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.deliver(NAKACK2.java:941)  org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.handleMessage(NAKACK2.java:830)  org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:610)  org.jgroups.protocols.BARRIER.up(BARRIER.java:170)  org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:129)\n\t\t... 9 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readWithExternalizer(GlobalMarshaller.java:694) org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNonNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:679) org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:361) org.infinispan.marshall.core.BytesObjectInput.readObject(BytesObjectInput.java:40) org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.readFrom(PutKeyValueCommand.java:121) org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readCommandParameters(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:103) org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readObject(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:92) org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readObject(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:54) org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readWithExternalizer(GlobalMarshaller.java:694) org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNonNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:677) org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:361) org.infinispan.marshall.core.BytesObjectInput.readObject(BytesObjectInput.java:40) org.infinispan.commands.remote.SingleRpcCommand.readFrom(SingleRpcCommand.java:47) org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readCommandParameters(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:103) org.infinispan.marshall.exts.CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.readObject(CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.java:116) org.infinispan.marshall.exts.CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.readObject(CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.java:57) org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readWithExternalizer(GlobalMarshaller.java:694) org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNonNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:677) org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:361) org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromObjectInput(GlobalMarshaller.java:199) org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(GlobalMarshaller.java:228) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processRequest(JGroupsTransport.java:1288) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processMessage(JGroupsTransport.java:1235) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.access$200(JGroupsTransport.java:121) org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport$ChannelCallbacks.receive(JGroupsTransport.java:1366) org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:819) org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:893) org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER.up(STATE_TRANSFER.java:128) org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:177) org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:359) org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:867) org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:240) org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:369) org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.deliver(NAKACK2.java:941) org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.handleMessage(NAKACK2.java:830) org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:610) org.jgroups.protocols.BARRIER.up(BARRIER.java:170) org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:129)\n\t... 9 common frames omitted",
```

To make ServerB up I need to change the HotRod port to 11228. Any idea why the port should be unique even on completely different server/Box?

No firewall issue/ port 11229 is not in use by any other application.

Regards,
Sarada.

Comment: What Infinispan version are you using? 
are you using any custom externalizer?

Comment: It's 8.2.4 Final. My Infinispan Server is an spring boot application.

Comment: Maybe you have an old server running on port 11229? Could you try with latest stable release Infinispan 9.1.3.Final and see if that works?